# Google Drive API POST requests?

Tags: python, google-drive-api, http-post

I'm trying to interact with the Google Drive API and while their example is working, I'd like to learn how to make the POST requests in python instead of using their pre-written methods. For example, in python how would I make the post request to insert a file?
[Insert a File](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert)

How do I add requests and parameters to the body?

Thanks!

UPDATE 1:

```
        headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + 'my auth token'}
        datax = {'name': 'upload.xlsx', 'parents[]': ['0BymNvEruZwxmWDNKREF1cWhwczQ']}
        r = requests.post('https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/', headers=headers, data=json.dumps(datax))
        response = json.loads(r.text)
        fileID = response['id']
        headers2 = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + 'my auth token'}
        r2 = requests.patch('https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/' + fileID + '?uploadType=media', headers=headers2)
```

Comment: Check this related [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20942626/filesinsert-google-drive-sdk-python-example-what-is-drive-api-service-ins?rq=1), I think it can give you an idea about POST request

Answer (score 0):

To insert a file:

1. Create a file in Google drive and get its *Id* in response
2. Insert a file using *Id*

Here are the POST parameters for both operations:

```
URL: 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files'
headers: 'Authorization Bearer <Token>'
Content-Type: application/json
body: { 
"name": "temp",
"mimeType": "<Mime type of file>"
}
```

In python you can use "Requests"

```
import requests
import json
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json','Authorization': 'Bearer <Your Oauth token' }
data = {'name': 'testing', 'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.document'}
r  = requests.post(url,headers=headers,data=json.dumps(data))
r.text
```

Above POST response will give you an id.
To insert in file use *PATCH* request with following parameters

```
url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/'<ID of file created> '?uploadType=media'
headers: 'Authorization Bearer <Token>'
Content-Type: <Mime type of file created>
body:  <Your text input>
```

I hope you can convert it in python requests.

Comment: Right now my code looks like what I posted in UPDATE 1. It just creates a blank json file titled 'untitled'. What am I doing wrong?